# How to code time slices for use with the range() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple function, but I am uncertain how to properly code the range portion that is causing an error. Are there best practices for dealing with data such as this?

```
mean_error = []
for time in range(0500-0515,0800-0815):
    train = melt[melt['Time'] < time]
    val = melt[melt['Time'] == time]

SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? As written these aren't ranges, they're invalid numeric literals that you're trying to subtract. What do you want `time` to be in each loop iteration?

Comment: I want time to be the range, but as you said it's a numerical literal. Is there a way to keep the numeric literal in the range or what is the best practice for changing numeric literal into something else that can be used as a range

Comment: "I want time to be the range" still doesn't make sense to me -- in the first iteration for example, `time` itself should represent the whole span of "0500 to 0515"? 
You then compare it against `melt['Time']` with a less-than operator - what is that value, and what does something being "less than 0500-0515" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range really only works on integers, so if you wanted to go this for loop route, the intuitive way would be to use the range to calculate the offset. And wrap that in a generator to produce the start and end times for each period.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_time = datetime(1,1,1, 5, 0) # We'll ignore date portion, it's set to 1st Jan, 0001

# Create a generator to produce tuples of start and end times (05:00, 05:15)
time_generator = (
    ((start_time + timedelta(minutes=mins)).time(), (start_time + timedelta(minutes=mins+15)).time())
    for mins in range(0, 195, 15)  # 195 = 3 hours & 15 minutes
)

for period_start, period_end in time_generator:
    print(period_start, period_end)  # You can delete this line, it just demos what this loop produces - these objects are `time` instances
    
    # You'll need to decide whether the time variable in your loop means period_start (e.g. 05:00) or period_end (e.g. 05:15) or both (e.g. tuple: (05:00, 05:15))
    # Assuming for now it means period_start
    train = melt[melt['Time'] < period_start]
    val = melt[melt['Time'] == period_start]
```